# What is the correct tense for を生み?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, tense, kana

> 一つの時代の積み重ねが新たな伝説を生み、ここにまた一人のヒーローが誕生した。ロックマン ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiH35lzjXTc))

Here are two translations I have:

> *The culmination of one era gives birth to a new legend, and here again another hero is born.*

> *The efforts of an era gave birth to a new legend, and here again another hero is born.*

I'm not sure if を生み is supposed to be を生み出した. Nor do I know what tense it could possibly mean exactly.

Is it "gave birth", "gives birth", "will give birth", "has given birth", or "produces a new legend", "created a new legend"?

Comment: Not your question, but 誕生した is "was born".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Any help is better than no help. I was wondering this too, since the second translation was given to me by a member in another website forum.

Comment: Generally verb in a form like 生み could be translated with the same tense as the main verb.  But, you could also avoid dealing with tense completely and translate it using a participle "giving birth to".

Comment: @SomaRise Just a quick tip: you don't have to post comments to thank helpful answerers and commenters. If you find an answer helpful, you should consider upvoting and/or accepting it. You have asked some 50 questions here on Japanese SE, but have rarely accepted any answers. Upvoting and accepting answers are the ways we express appreciation on SE. :)

Comment: Oh ok. I'm just always on Wordreference and Reddit so I never noticed this until you pointed it out to me. Thanks for the helpful information.

Comment: If you are asking if the first part of the sentence refers to the creation of a particular legend (like the second refers to the birth of a particular hero) or a timeless truth (about an era), I would say the answer is the former. It’s something that has already happened.

Answer (score 2):

As Japanese, を生み has no tense at all.  Tense for this only exists when translating into a language that requires a tense.

In your given context, を生み occurs within a longer statement that ends with 誕生した -- past tense, and the only tense in the entire sentence.  So if we were forced to translate を生み here into an expression that has tense, the past tense might be appropriate.  That said, I personally like @[A.Ellett](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4875/)'s suggestion of side-stepping the issue, and using *"giving birth to"*, a construction in English that itself doesn't really have tense.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. But: "The efforts of an era giving birth to a new legend, and here again another hero is born.", doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The part before the comma can be analyzed as a kind of stage-setting, a way of establishing the context.  That kind of rhetorical feature in English is sometimes carried out using a clause like _"**With** XYZ be**ing** the case, ..."_.  The sample sentence could be translated as _"**With** the events of one age **giving rise to** a new legend, ..."_